# How to use UINavigationController in UITabBarController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a `UITabBarController` that each tab has an `UINavigationController`. One of them has a blank `rootViewController` that pushed another `viewController`, in `viewDidLoad` and `viewDidAppear` functions (I use this presenterVC because I need to reset the AddVC when user uses another tab)

```
class PresenterVC: UIViewController { // This is root viewController

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.PresentCheckAddVC()

    }
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        self.PresentCheckAddVC()

    }

    func PresentCheckAddVC() {
        if self.navigationController?.viewControllers.count == 1 {
            let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AddVC")

            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: false)
        }
    }

}
```

The problem is that I need to navigate to another `viewController` in AddVC, but it automatically navigates back to AddVC.
I tried both segue and manually pushing `viewController`, and they have same results.

```
class AddVC: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func btnPayeeSelect_Pressed(_ sender: Any) {
        PresentPayeeAddVC()        
    }

    func PresentPayeeAddVC() {
        let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PayeeAddVC")

        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not really understand your problem. Please explain a bit more what's going wrong and show some more code. Except of that you talk about presenting view controllers but I do not see any presentation code. Although I do not understand your problem at all I am sure that you do not want to call `PresentCheckAddVC` in `viewDidLoad` AND `viewDidAppear`.

Comment: @AndréSlotta I'm creating an instance of AddVC(my custom viewController), and pushing it to navigationController. And in AddVC I need to push another viewController, but it navigates back to AddVC again.

Comment: Then please show some of your `AddVC` code.

Comment: @AndréSlotta I've added some new code ;)

Comment: And what happens in `PayeeAddVC`? Because only with this code it should not navigate back automatically...

Comment: @AndréSlotta nothing happens in PayeeAddVC. I've commented all functions called in viewDidLoad and  tableView delegates. FYI PayeeAddVC is UITableViewController. 
But still it's navigating back to AddVC automatically